# How to change geolocation using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying change my location using Python's Selenium package. I've tried some code, but they didn't work for me. It keeps showing my location as `Germany`. But I want it to be `United Arab Emirates`.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Driver and link
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

params = {
    "latitude": 25.2048,
    "longitude": 55.2708,
    "accuracy": 100
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/musta/Desktop/Amazon/Yazılım/Product Price Tracker/chromedriver.exe', options = options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/b07h9fldcd")

getText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span#price_inside_buybox").text
print(getText.strip())

getText2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".a-size-base.a-color-secondary").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(getText2.strip())

driver.close()
```

And this is the output:

```
$109.72
$43.78 Shipping & Import Fees Deposit to Germany
```

But I want this output:

```
$109.72
# I think this amount ($43.78) of money will be change due to location.
$43.78 Shipping & Import Fees Deposit to United Arab Emirates
```

How can I achieve this result? I want my location as `United Arab Emirates` instead of `Germany`. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/chrome_devtools/

Comment: It's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your `latitude`, `longitude`, `accuracy` is correct.

Then I think you are just missing the `dict()` function.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/musta/Desktop/Amazon/Yazılım/Product Price Tracker/chromedriver.exe', options = options)
params = dict({
        "latitude": 25.2048,
        "longitude": 55.2708,
        "accuracy": 100
        })
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/b07h9fldcd")
```

Few of the line of code is not in sequence. So you need to correct that too.